# How can I get more sniper ammo?

Tags: halo-reach

In Halo Reach I love to use the sniper rifle. The only problem is it runs out of ammo and there's no way to pickup ammo for the rifle in the campaign.

Because this is Xbox there is no commands and no console to allow me to gain ammo from the stockpiles. So, is there anyway (with skulls or game bonuses) that I can gain ammo for the sniper in the campaign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the campaign, the short answer is you can't gain ammo easily. That's a part of the trade-off for the power of the sniper rifle and other guns like the rocket launcher and things. That's how they are balanced. You just have to search around and try and find ammo for it, and do your best to conserve it as you go. Keeping a good secondary is always helpful.

That said, you *can* for custom games. There is an option to turn on bottomless clips for custom games where you have unlimited ammo. It is a custom game type option under the weapons and damage menu.